# Error return new SearchInput. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying this code and I got an error say System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when I run the website even though this code worked well in the tutorial.

```
private SearchInput GetSearchInput()
        {
            return new SearchInput()
            {
                id = txt_id.Text,
                email = txt_email.Text,
                gender = ddl_gender.SelectedItem.Text,
                fname = txt_fname.Text,
                lname = txt_lname.Text
            };

        }
```

I am coding on ASP.NET and C#. Please help.

I tried to put a variable

```
private SearchInput GetSearchInput()
        {
            SearchInput newinput = new SearchInput()
            {
                id = txt_id.Text,
                email = txt_email.Text,
                gender = ddl_gender.SelectedItem.Text,
                fname = txt_fname.Text,
                lname = txt_lname.Text
            };
            return newinput;
        }
```

but it still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the problem is not with the `object` you are returning but with `ddl_gender.SelectedItem.Text`. My guess is either `ddl_gender` is `null` or `ddl_gender.SelectedItem` is `null`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So what suggestions will be helpful in this case? I put genders into a dropdown list so as far as I know, I have to use SelectedItem to return the value.

Comment: I tried to remove the 'gender = ddl_gender.SelectedItem.Text' and it works well. So you are true that this dropdown list causes this null error. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I got the solution. I must load the gender dropdown list first in Page_Load before loading other protected voids.